# Calculate quantity in a faster way than in this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate total available qty from the database, and for that I need to do joins with a couple of tables. I can not paste my whole query, but the following is the basic structure:

```
select sum(qty) as qty, field
from
(
  (
      select SUM(table1.qty) as qty , field
       from
       table1
       left join table2 on table1.field = table2.field
       left join table3 on table3.field = table2.field
       where condition
       group by fieldname
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
       selecy SUM(table1.qty) as qty,field 
       from
       table1
       left join table2 on table1.field = table2.field
       left join table3 on table3.field = table2.field
       where condition
       group by fieldname
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
       select SUM(table1.qty) as qty, field
       from
       table1
       left join table2 on table1.field = table2.field
       left join table3 on table3.field = table2.field
       where condition
       group by fieldname
   )
  ...
  ..
  12 times
) as temp
LEFT JOIN another_main_table ON another_main_table.field = temp.field
```

I have taken care of indexes of each table, but there are some unions which are taking longer time than expected. There are around 45 tables used in this query and all are examined fully. Some tables have around 2.6 million records.
Can you please suggest me how I can get the result in 1/2 seconds? As of now I am getting the result in around one minute.

Comment: It isn't clear what you need to do with this query. Are table1,table2,table3 the same in all queries? If so just use one query with `WHERE Condition1 OR Condition2 OR .....`

Comment: It may be an ugly query, but you might need to post the more complete query.  You may even need to post it to some off-site location like pastebin.com if it is too large to accept here.

Comment: hey .. All tables table1, table2, table3 are different.

I know if i could paste query here it would be more easier to guide me..but can not post query here because .. I am bounded not to reveal information about database and tables:(. Sorry for that.

Comment: Is the `field` column in your select statement meant to be the same as the `fieldname` column you are grouping by? Just to clarify, is the only difference in each part of the union the where condition, or do the other parts vary as well? If it's just the where condition which change, it may be possible to write it as a single query.

Comment: Nope Fieldname are also different in all unions and all tables and where conditions are also different

Comment: Does your report need to be on time allways? Can it show you only yesterday data or has to be on time?

Comment: For us to assist you, you really need to post your full query. Then it can be tested, tweaked and reposted with advice. One way you can do that is search and replace all your field and table names with something that doesn't reveal company info. Then post here and let us have a crack at helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Since your given example one can not properly justify the proper solutions, but still if I roughly examine your query, you have used LEFT JOIN, So this will take a longer time compare to INNER JOIN.

So, Use INNER JOIN if your data permits